# jQuery table rotate rows and columns

Tags: javascript, rotation

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to rotate it with names.
`Factoryname` should be top and `Generals` should be shown at left side, as you can see in the above image.

Actually, I rotate but `count1` , `count2` and `count3` doesnt rotate , it is showing on the top in different places of my table as it does inside the table,

How I can rotate the whole table? Could anyone help me pls? I need an idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can do easily if you change the table layout in a flex layout, you can infact changing row and direction changing the flex-directions: column in flex-direction: row and flex-direction: row in flex-direction: column, it's easier than a pure table and you can changing easier the align, the vertical-align and more other things, search on google display:flex

Comment: Do you see my picture which I added ?

Comment: Thank you so much David , I added also display :flex before but it couldnt work, The rotate is working but i cant rotate it all of my data goes out of the table

Comment: you should change the structure, you must have this tructure
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
   <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"></div>
   <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"></div>
</div>
and change the direction with javascript
this is a little guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
If you like the layouts you will love the display flex